# Show that the function $f(x,y)=\int_b^yf_2(a,t)\ dt + \int_a^xf_1(t,y)\ dt $ is a potential function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $F=(f_1,f_2)$ be conservative over the open rectangle:

$$R=\{(x,y):|x-a|<r,|y-b|<r\} $$

I need to show that the function $f(x,y)=\int_b^yf_2(a,t)\ dt + \int_a^xf_1(t,y)\ dt $ is a potential function for $F$ in $R$.

I was suggested to use line integrals to integrate $F$ along the segment that passes through $(a,b)$ to $(a,y)$, and  along the segment that passes through $(a,y$) to $(x,y)$.

I defined this segments by:
$$\theta_1(t)=(1-t)(a,b)+t(a,y)$$ 
$$\theta_2(t)=(1-t)(a,y)+t(x,y)$$

For $t$ in $[0,1]$. However, I don't know how to proceed from here to show that actually $F=\nabla f  $. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure about the parameters of $f_1$ and $f_2$? That is, that $f_1$ is a function of y but $f_2$ is not a function of x? Perhaps the following Wikipedia page can help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign

Answer (score 1):

The expression $f(x,y)= \int_b^y f_2(a,\eta) d\eta + \int_b^y f_1(a,\xi) d\xi$
is the line integral of $F$ along the polyline $(a,b)-(a,y)-(x,y)$, because $d\xi=0$ on the first segment and $d\eta=0$ on the second segment.

The integral is path-indendent, so we obtain the same value along the polyline $(a,b)-(x,b)-(x,y)$. Therefore,
$$
f(x,y) 
= \int_b^y f_2(a,\eta) d\eta + \int_a^x f_1(\xi,y) d\xi
= \int_a^x f_1(\xi,b) d\xi + \int_b^y f_2(x,\eta) d\eta
$$

By the Newton-Leibniz formula, the first line integral gives
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) = f_1(x,y);
$$
the second line integral gves
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y) = f_2(x,y);
$$
So $\nabla f=F$.

Comment: What conditions guarantee that the line integral is path-independent in the set $R$?

Comment: $F$ is differentiable then ($F$ has an antiderivative $\Leftrightarrow$ the line integral of $F$ is path-independent ($F$ is conservative) $\Leftrightarrow$ $\partial_1 F_2 = \partial_2 F_1$.) (The last $\Leftarrow$ is valid only in simply connected domains.)